# Decompress FlateDecode Objects in PDF in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying the following code to decompress data in PDF

```
import re
import zlib

pdf = open("some_doc.pdf", "rb").read()
stream = re.compile(r'.*?FlateDecode.*?stream(.*?)endstream', re.S)

for s in stream.findall(pdf):
    s = s.strip('\r\n')
    try:
        print(zlib.decompress(s))
        print("")
    except:
        pass
```

But it is show me the following error
  File "D:\pdf_flatedecode.py", line 8, in 
    for s in stream.findall(pdf):
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
Please help me. I am not able to finding out the problem. My python version is 3.7.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Core problem is that you open your pdf in 'binary'-mode, so you have to compile your regex from bytes, not from str. I'm not sure 100% it's working the way you supposed to, but try this:

```
import re
import zlib

pdf = open("some_doc.pdf", "rb").read()
stream = re.compile(b'.*?FlateDecode.*?stream(.*?)endstream', re.S)

for s in re.findall(stream,pdf):
    s = s.strip(b'\r\n')
    try:
        print(zlib.decompress(s).decode('UTF-8'))
        print("")
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Your code fails silently if any exception of any kind is thrown. That is a very bad idea. `except anything: pass` If any error occurs, of any kind, while trying to decode the pdf, then nothing gets printed to the console, the script does nothing. We don't even know that an error occured.

Comment: Would this work for Arabic (R2L) as well? PDF was created using Microsoft Reporting Services PDF Rendering Extension 13.0.0.0.